# Error in loop when trying to make my array of labels match a list from another class

Tags: arrays, list, forms, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a loop that will change my array of labels to match a list from another class. I declared the list as

ADDITIONAL INFO: I am creating a payroll program. When the Pay button is clicked for an employee, the Status list with that employee index gets updated into "Paid". I want the label on the other form to reflect the word "Paid" as well

```
private List<string> Status = new List<string>(2);

        public List<string> GetList()
        {
            return Status;
        }
 private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            Status.Add("Unpaid");
            Status.Add("Paid");
            Status.Add("Unpaid");
}
```

And in the second form

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    { Label[] Labels = new Label[3];

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Labels[0] = this.lblTony;
            Labels[1] = this.lblSteve;
            Labels[2] = this.lblPeter;


            Form1 f1 = new Form1 (); 

            for (int i = 0; i !=3 ; i++)
            {
                List<string> Status = f1.GetList();
                Labels[i].Text = Status[i];

            }
        }

    }
```

'''

I tried to only put the relevant codes but I may be missing something? The error is IndexOutOfRangeException which I do not get because the are the same size. I tried changing the sizes but the error only changes to argumentoutofbounds

Comment: I have no idea what `Position` is in your first code block but there are many things that smell bad in the code snippets you have posted. From what I can see, `Status` has no elements since you have not shown the code where you call `Status.Add()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
status.Add(lables[i].Text);
```

insted of

```
lables[i].Text = status[i];
```

I Dont Test it But I think its going to work!
go forward

Comment: I tried this but it still gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that are not great in the code you have shown but if you want to follow this approach then why not just:

```
class Form1
{
    private List<string> Status = new List<string>();

    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        return Status;
    }

    // I'm guessing as to how you add elements to Status
    public Form1()
    {
        Status.Add("Item 1");
        Status.Add("Item 2");
        Status.Add("Item 3");
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Label[] Labels = new Label[3];

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Labels[0] = this.lblTony;
        Labels[1] = this.lblSteve;
        Labels[2] = this.lblPeter;
        
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        List<string> Status = f1.GetList();
        
        Debug.Assert(Labels.Length == Status.Count());

        for (int i = 0; i < Status.Count(); ++i)
        {
            Labels[i].Text = Status[i];
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like your main problem is that you have allocated a space of 2 for Status when you construct the object but then run the loop for 3 when copying the values over. If you are using a `List` you rarely need to pre-allocate its size.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to coding C#  but I do not get the solution. I'm just trying to make the label array text become the status list from form1. I did what you suggested and it made an even longer error when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

I would create your Label array using this kind of syntax so you don't have to specify a size:

```
Label[] Labels;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Labels = new Label[] { this.lblTony, this.lblSteve, this.lblPeter };
}
```

Also, I suspect that you're getting the error because of this line in Form2:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1 ();
```

...as this is creating an "invisible" instance of Form1 and is likely not the Form1 on your screen where presumably the "btnFind" button was clicked to add items to the List (is that a typo in your posted code?).

If that's the case, then you need a reference to the actual visible Form1. You can do use by either passing Form1 into Form2 via a constructor or method, via the `Show()` method, or by iteration over the `Application.OpenForms` collection and finding Form1 there.

> I'm just trying to make the label array text become the status list
> from form1.

Here's one way to pass Form1 into Form2 via the `Show()` method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... in Form1 ...
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show(this); // <-- pass Form1 via "this"
}
```

Now, over in Form2, you can cast `this.Owner` back to Form1 and use that to access the list:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... in Form2 ...
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
    List<String> status = f1.GetList();
    // ... do something with "status" ...
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to coding C# but yes I do get the error in form line but I do not get the solution. I'm just trying to make the label array text become the status list from form1.

Comment: See the code added to the bottom of my post above.